# Android failed to open file

Tags: android, cordova, html5-video

I have a video element:

```
<video><source src="path/video.webm" type="video/webm"></video>
```

This plays on Firefox and Chrome without any problems. However, when I run in on Android (emulator 4.1) it doesn't and logcat shows me this error:

> Failed to open file '/android_asset/www/path/video.webm'. (No such
>   file or directory)

The video is included in the apk under the path `assets/www/path/video.webm`, which should be correct.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: How are you loading your WebView?

Comment: @323go I use the default Cordova 2.6 project template without any modifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Cordova does not support video or audio files stored inside the app. A solution is to copy the file to the internal storage and open it from there.

Quoting from [CB-6079](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6079):

> The assets directory is an alias to the APK. An APK is like a JAR
>   file, it's a special type of ZIP file that has the application's
>   classes in it, as well as its resources and assets. For any file to be
>   accessed from the assets, it must be decompressed. This is trivial for
>   files that aren't video, but apparently due to the nature of video
>   files, Android isn't able to decompress these files and play them.
>   Therfore all video files must be stored on the real file system
>   somewhere, and not in the APK.

Comment: Wait, really? At all? Is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

For Android try to use 'file:///android_asset/www/path/video.webm'

But I think this solution won't work on other platforms.